# Detect in TComponent descendant that parent form is about to be destroyed

Tags: delphi

I made my own UDP receiver a `TComponent` descendant. It has an `OnReceive` event. This event is used to add a line to `TMemo` which exists on the same form.

The problem is that when parent form is being destroyed `TMemo` gets destroyed first and UDP receiver continues to fire `OnReceive` event. Of course I get an exception when I try to `mmo1.Lines.Add(S)` to a non-existent Memo.

How to detect in `TComponent` the moment when parent form and it's components are about to be destroyed, but aren't destroyed yet? I would do then a proper receiver thread shutdown.

Comment: Why do you care about the parent form? if you are after the Memo, you better use the notification mechanism via `FreeNotification`. then when the Memo is destroyed your component will be notified via the `Notification` virtual method.

Comment: Ok I misread your question. You could set `OnReceive := nil` when the form destroys. `Detect in TComponent descendant that parent form is about to be destroyed` is not what you want. a `TComponent` has no *Parent*. it has an Owner which *may* be a form or other `TComponent` and it can also be `nil`.

Comment: @Paul: `TIdUDPServer` has internal listening threads for its `Bindings, and those threads are synchronized with the main UI thread by default, and are terminated in the component destructor if the server is still active. You can set the server's `Active` property to false in the form's `OnClose` or `OnDestroy` event, which are triggered before the Memo is destroyed. You can do the same thing with your UDP component - deactivate it before the Form is actually destroyed. Or, simply don't fire its `OnReceive` event, or at least don't access the Memo, if the form's `csDestroying` flag is true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you rely on components for your component to work but are not able to control their life-cycle, you can use TComponent's [Notification](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TComponent_Notification.html) to re-act when the component you are interested in gets destroyed.

First, your UDP Receiver will need to add itself to the notification list of the component with e.g.

`Form.FreeNotification(Self);`

to receive notifications from the TForm. Then, the UDP Receiver needs to override

`procedure Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation); 
virtual;`

There, you can listen to notifications where `AComponent = Form` and `Operation = opRemove`, that will indicate the Form is being removed.

Edit: Reading again, this might not be what you are interested in. If the OnReceive event is implemented in your form, you might check if the Form's [ComponentState](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TComponentState) includes [csDestroying](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Destroying).

Or, in case the `Memo` is created at design-time, or you explicitly create and free-and-nil the `Memo` yourself, just check if `Memo <> nil`.

Comment: Checking for `Memo <> nil` is pointless unless you explicitly Free **and** `nil` it.

Comment: This is true, good point. I'll refine the answer with that comment.

Comment: @kobik When a component is destroyed, if its Owner has a `published` pointer to the component then that pointer is automatically `nil`'ed. That is handled by a call to `TComponent.SetReference(False)` during the component's destruction, which calls the Owner's `FieldAddress()` method to find the pointer and then `nil` it if found. So, for example, when the `TForm1.Memo1` object is destroyed, the `TForm1.Memo1` field pointer gets `nil`'ed.

Comment: @Remy It maybe so for published components but I would not rely on it in my code. In any case, this is good information to know.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you even trying to detect in your component when the parent form is destroyed? Wouldn't it be better to just utilize forms `OnClose` or `OnCloseQuery` events to stop your component from receiving data.

Both of these events are called before the form even begins destroying itself and its owned components. Where in `OnCloseQuery` event you can even prevent form from closing if certain work hasn't finished yet.